# NodeJS server posts not responding

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am running some api tests on my NodeJS server hosted on a domain(server.domainname.com) while posting requests from my local development environment(ie. localhost:3000).
The problem I face is upon an **axios post** to the server, I get a:
`404 Not Found` whereas all the resources and paths are configured in the server file.
Here's a snippet:

```
const mailData = {
    fname: 'FirstName',
    lname: 'LastName',
    mail: 'email@example.com',
    amountPaid: 25
}
axios.post("https://server.domainname.com/topup", mailData).then(() => {
              console.log('post success')
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            })
```

Here is the api configuration for to receive this path in my server file:

```
app.post('/topup', (req, res, next) => {
  let mailDetails = req.body;
  sendEmail(mailDetails, "topUp");
  next();
})
```

Unfourtunately, it logs `Error: Request failed with status code 404` in the console and in the browser developer tools same: `POST https://server.domain.com/topup 404 Not Found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `res.end()`

```
app.post('/topup', (req, res, next) => {
  let mailDetails = req.body;
  sendEmail(mailDetails, "topUp");
  res.end() // add this! 
  next();
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I did to solve it thanks. But I don't know the reason why it works with the response send

Comment: I'm sorry for replying late.
When you send a POST/popup request, it is right to enter the phrase below and send an email as intended.

`app.post('/topup', (req, res, next) => {
  let mailDetails = req.body;
  sendEmail(mailDetails, "topUp");
  next();
})
`

But the problem is after that.
Since response is not set, when next() is called, context finds the next middleware. At this time, 404 occurs because it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

> https://server.domainname.com/topup

should be switched to the domain you're using or
you could try just **/topup**

```
const mailData = {
    fname: 'FirstName',
    lname: 'LastName',
    mail: 'email@example.com',
    amountPaid: 25
}
axios.post("/topup", mailData).then(() => {
              console.log('post success')
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            })
```

Comment: I don't think so